# Diagnose "no frame!" error of fragmented MP4

Tags: mp4, fmp4

IMHO, MP4 (ISO/IEC 14496-12) is quite complicated. This question is meant for those familiar with ins and outs of MP4, so I try to be brief. Otherwise, this question could be a long essay.

I am trying to create fMP4 with C# (the language is not relevant here). The created fMP4 file does not play. Using the tool ffprobe to check the file generates the following:

```
ffprobe  "foo.mp4"
[h264 @ 0000021625d10e40] no frame!
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'foo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1mp42isomiso6
    creation_time   : 2022-09-11T00:24:35.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:10.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2078 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:5], 2077 kb/s, 12.22 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 2000k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-09-11T00:24:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

Please note the error:

```
[h264 @ 0000021625d10e40] no frame!
```

When I use:

```
 ffprobe -show_frames "foo.mp4"
```

It shows hundreds of frames of this small MP4 file that seem flawless. I cannot paste them here there are thousands of lines.  However, ffprobe shows two errors at the start:

```
[h264 @ 000001b015110ec0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001b01545e7c0] no frame!
```

Please note these two "no frame!" errors generated by ffprobe -show_frames are different from the first one by ffprobe without the -show_frames option.

I wonder if anyone could offer a tip about what these "no frame!" errors mean and where I should chase the culprit.

The following is what Mp4 Explorer shows:

[image]

**Update 2022-09-17**
Here is an fMP4 file: [example.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CGw2ReECVs0L6EDFP1Zs_WV9KzjUzZJw/view?usp=sharing). Every video player seems to be able to play it except for VLC Player. VLC Player is an important player. I would love to make it work for it. Could anyone offer a clue about why VLC Player does not like it?
[image]

Comment: **(1)** Can you provide a link to your output MP4 file (test video can even be just a static background colour)? **(2)** Does the MP4 play okay in some media player (and FFprobe is the only problem)?

Comment: @VC.One Thank you for trying to help. Nothing was working yesterday (i.e., no player can play the fMP4 file). I have just tried to produce a file per your request, and completely to my surprise, Windows Photos can play it though VLC Player cannot. It still has the error. Something must be wrong. Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q8MSgnmWI4s0VOCcHx3sSB_Ki4W7bf1j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @VC.One I edited the question and added a sample fMP4 file.